# Loading a URL inside a TXT in a Webview

Tags: java, android

I'm making a kind of browser app. It's working just like I want except for one thing. I have to load a URL that is inside a `.txt` in my WebView. The `.txt` will be in the device root directory and the user will be able to edit this `.txt` using the app. How can I do it?

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abaco.abawser.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.abaco.awser;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView web;
    String webURL = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.web)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.loadUrl(webURL);
        web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        this.web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        web.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        web.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried yet? Have you looked up how to load file in Java / Android APIs, or how to use a `FileReader`? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Comment: I never used anything that involves files in the device HD :(

Comment: Are you sure you want to put the file in the "device root directory"? As in "/" rather than "/sdcard/" ?

Comment: No, it can be anywhere in the Device HD

Comment: @MarcosSartorato I feel like your question is lacking explanation about `.txt` file. Will it come with your app or user will have to create it on his phone for your app to work? Because if you will ship this `.txt` file with your app, you can put it in resources. Do you want user to be able to change it or do you just use it in your program?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you want to write visited urls to a .txt file?

Comment: I want to load a url writed in a txt in my webview.

Comment: Can you help me again??

Answer (score 11):

There are two *separate* concerns here:

1. getting a URL from the .txt file
2. loading a URL in `WebView`

You should think of them separately. You already seem to know how to do 2. (load a URL into `WebView`), so focus on 1.

You can learn how to open and read a file in Java from many resources. Including [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java). The only Android specific part is accessing the file. Android applications have restricted access to most storage locations. On user (not rooted) devices, apps have access to only few location:

#### Application Storage

Each app can access own storage (in `/data/data/{your.package}`). You can open these files directly using [`openFileInput`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)). Or get the path using [`getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).

#### External Storage

If the file is in `/sdcard` your app will need the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and you might have to ensure that external storage is mounted. [Learn more here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

#### `/data/local/tmp`

This is one location on most Android devices (but **not all**) that all apps can "enter", so if you put the file in there and make sure it's world readable (`chmod o+r /data/local/tmp/myfile.txt`) then you will be able to open it in any app.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to support the approach of @szym. Here you can find some code for your better understanding.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
    }
    br.close();

String url = "";

String urlRegex = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher urlMatcher = pattern.matcher(text.toString());

    while (urlMatcher.find())
    {
        url = text.toString().substring(urlMatcher.start(0),
                urlMatcher.end(0));
        break;
    }

    if(""!=url){
         WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }

}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```